# How to get the semantic orientation of String or adjectives by using SentiWordNet

Tags: java, wordnet, sentiment-analysis

I am doing a  project on sentiment analysis. I need  the semantic orientation of String or adjectives so I recommended  to use SentiWordNet_3.0.0 from the reference post of Stackoverflow ”How to use SentiWordNet”.I had run the  code but every time I get the following output.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 
at qtag.SWN3.(SWN3.java:29) 
at qtag.SWN3.main(SWN3.java:105) 
0.0
```

I have run the code with different  string as input,but the result is same . I already removed the first part or garbage part of the file SentiWordNet_3.0.0_20130122.txt.What is the problem with my code.what should i do now? please help me. Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;
public class SWN3 {

private String pathToSWN = "C:/Users/Monalisa/Desktop/SentiWordNet_3.0.0/home/swn/www/admin/dump/SentiWordNet_3.0.0_20130122.txt";
        private HashMap<String, Double>_dict;

        public SWN3(){

            _dict = new HashMap<String, Double>();
            HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String, Vector<Double>>();
            try{
                BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
                String line = "";           
                while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] data = line.split("\t");
                    Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                    String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
                    for(String w:words)
                    {
                        String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                        w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                        if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                        {
                            Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                            if(index>v.size())
                                for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                                    v.add(0.0);
                            v.add(index, score);
                            _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                            for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                                v.add(0.0);
                            v.add(index, score);
                            _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();
                for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    String word = iterator.next();
                    Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
                    double score = 0.0;
                    double sum = 0.0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                        score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
                    for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                        sum += (double)1/(double)i;
                    score /= sum;
                    String sent = "";               
                    if(score>=0.75)
                        sent = "strong_positive";
                    else
                    if(score > 0.25 && score<=0.5)
                        sent = "positive";
                    else
                    if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                        sent = "weak_positive";
                    else
                    if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                        sent = "weak_negative";
                    else
                    if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                        sent = "negative";
                    else
                    if(score<=-0.75)
                        sent = "strong_negative";
                    _dict.put(word, score);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
        }

public Double extract(String word)
{
   Double total = new Double(0);
    if(_dict.get(word+"#n") != null)
         total = _dict.get(word+"#n") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#a") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#a") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#r") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#r") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#v") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#v") + total;
    return total;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SWN3 test = new SWN3();
    String sentence="what a super great day";
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+"); 
    double totalScore = 0;
    for(String word : words) {
        word = word.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
        if (test.extract(word) == null)
            continue;
        totalScore += test.extract(word);
    }
    System.out.println(totalScore);
}

}
```

Comment: private HashMap<String, Double_dict;
this should be like this ` private HashMap<String,Double> _dict ;`

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that you have taken the source code from the given example on sentiwordnet (sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it) . So the problem is in the sentiwordnet_3.0.0_20130122.txt" file.... it should start with the 1st adjective so remove all the comments ....and at the end there are some extra space remove them.
So in a nutshell the start of the file the first line should be

`**a    00001740    0.125   0   able#1  (usually followed by to) having the necessary means or skill or know-how or authority to do something; "able to swim"; "she was ........**`

and the end of the file the last line should be

`**v   02772310    0.125   0   deflagrate#1    cause to burn rapidly and with great intensity; "care must be exercised when this substance is to be deflagrated"**`

Besides this should be mistake i think so but correct it
`private HashMap<String,Double> _dict ;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually when I had run my code it was         " private HashMap<String,Double> _dict ",By mistake '>' has removed when i write the code here. The first line of file is: **a 00001740 0.125 0 able#1 (usually followed by to) having the necessary means or skill or know-how or authority to do something; "able to swim"; "she was ........**