# java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String in SentiWordNet

Tags: java, wordnet, numberformatexception

hi i am new to wordnet api, i tried to run code below for the SentiWordNet. and i got the code from [How to get the semantic orientation of String or adjectives by using SentiWordNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410344/how-to-get-the-semantic-orientation-of-string-or-adjectives-by-using-sentiwordne) this stackoverflow.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;
public class SWN3 {

private String pathToSWN = "C:/Users/raj/Desktop/Abhi/Wordnet/SentiWordNet/home/swn/www/admin/dump/SentiWordNet_3.0.0_20130122.txt";
        private HashMap<String, Double> _dict;


        public SWN3(){

            _dict = new HashMap<String, Double>();
            HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String, Vector<Double>>();

            try{

                BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
                String line ="";           
                while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] data = line.split("\t");
                    Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                    String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
                    for(String w:words)
                    {
                        String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                        w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                        if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                        {
                            Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                            if(index>v.size())
                                for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                                    v.add(0.0);
                            v.add(index, score);
                            _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                            for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                                v.add(0.0);
                            v.add(index, score);
                            _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();

                for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

                    String word = iterator.next();
                    Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
                    double score = 0.0;
                    double sum = 0.0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                        score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
                    for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                        sum += (double)1/(double)i;
                    score /= sum;

                    String sent = ""; 

                    if(score>=0.75)
                        sent = "strong_positive";
                    else
                    if(score > 0.25 && score<=0.5)
                        sent = "positive";
                    else
                    if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                        sent = "weak_positive";
                    else
                    if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                        sent = "weak_negative";
                    else
                    if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                        sent = "negative";
                    else
                    if(score<=-0.75)
                        sent = "strong_negative";
                    _dict.put(word, score);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
        }

public Double extract(String word)
{
   Double total = new Double(0);
    if(_dict.get(word+"#n") != null)
         total = _dict.get(word+"#n") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#a") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#a") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#r") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#r") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#v") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#v") + total;
    return total;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SWN3 test = new SWN3();

    String sentence="what a super great day";

    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+"); 

    double totalScore = 0;

    for(String word : words) {

        word = word.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
        if (test.extract(word) == null)
            continue;
        totalScore += test.extract(word);
    }
    System.out.println(totalScore);
}

}
```

butb gets following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at org.test.SWN3.<init>(SWN3.java:27)
    at org.test.SWN3.main(SWN3.java:104)
```

pls thnks

Comment: Please provide the line where the error occurs. Additionally, it seems the value you want to parse as double is empty.

Answer (score 0):

What result would you expect here e.g. if `line` does not have enough elements separated by Tab (even worse: what if it is empty and you are using arrays)?

```
String[] data = line.split("\t");
Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2]) - ...
```

same here, what if there are not enough elements separated by a hash:

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
```